# TFS User Profiles Username Does Not Match Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, team-foundation-server

We are using TFS V.15. It's my understanding TFS sits on top of SharePoint and SharePoint gets user updates from Active Directory. I was under the impression TFS users get updated from TFSJobAgent.exe. TFSJobAgent.exe seems to be running successfully but there are a couple of names in TFS that are not changing. For example we have one user where their name in TFS has a period at the end of it.  I can remove the period in the tfs_configuration database in the dbo.tbl.Identity table in the DisplayName column and the name reverts back to having a period at the end of it after a few minutes. The user has no such period in his various name properties in Active Directory.

Where is TFS getting this displayname value?

The Sid in the TFS database matches the Sid in Active Directory.

Comment: Also... when I look at the Job History at https://mytfsinstance:17012/_admin/ServiceJobDefinitions.aspx I do not see a Job with the description of Synching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TFS users can edit their profile to update their display name to something different than AD, but it will still use the SID to sync name changes for non-edited users

Comment: I have another user who's name did sync back to AD with the exception of one project.  In the project itself it shows the correct user display name but if I try to assign him to a User Story his name comes up incorrectly in the search.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly a cache issue on the server? Very weird.

Comment: If you've already looked at the DB, I think you can see a flag if the name is overridden plus the last sync time. I believe this is in Tfs_Configuration rather than the collection db

Comment: The displayname in the database looks fine.  Not sure why the one collection is showing the old name.

Comment: It's actually happening on one team.  If I go to add the member to the team the name still comes up wrong.  If I try to add the same member to any other team the display name looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

TFS read Active Directory every hour to sync data (see details [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vasu_sankaran/2010/06/07/identity-synchronization-in-team-foundation-server-2010/)).
It is not advisable to directly edit TFS databases unless instructed by Microsoft Support (and you have a sound backup anyway).
As @nschonni said, TFS permits users to override some data, like the display name, and this is you simplest work-around.

*Note*: SharePoint has no share in TFS. You can setup integration but they are otherwise independent.